# Angular js Date Formatting

Tags: angularjs, date, format

I want to change the date format from 10/07/2015(mm/dd/yyyy) to oct 7 ,2015 in angular js
 i'm using {{'10/07/2015' | date:'longDate'}} and is giving me the same date '10/07/2015' as output 
can any one help me with this?

Comment: The date filter only accepts: `Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.`

Comment: If your format your string to ISO 8601, for example `2015-10-07` it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [per the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), you have to format your date in a specific way for the date filter to work properly:

Documentation:

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various >ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter >versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone >is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local >timezone.

Example ISO formatted:

```html
<div>{{ "2015-10-07" | date:'longDate' }}</div>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvc2cLqc/)</kbd>